# change microsoft compiler from vc14 to vc12 in devenv.exe

Tags: c++, devenv, msvc12

I compile command line most of my applications using msvc12's vsvarsall.bat and setting the platform.  Now I have a project that comes with a visual studio solution and it compiles with msvc14.  To keep compatability I would like to compile with vc12.  How do I switch compilers inside devenv.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Open the project in msvc, then go to "Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset".

[image: corresponding properties page]